# Several errors in linked list counter

Tags: c

so I'm creating a linked list counter for fun, here's my program.

**WHAT I WANT:**
I want it to give me the correct count

**WHAT I GET:**
The following errors:

```
linkedlist.c:12: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
linkedlist.c:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
linkedlist.c: In function ‘main’:
linkedlist.c:22: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
linkedlist.c:23: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
linkedlist.c:24: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
linkedlist.c:25: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

**MY CODE**
I realize that this isn't a good way to instantiate a linked list. That doesn't matter though, what I'm stressing is that my counter works.

I have made some amendments to my code. No, this is not a c++ program, it actually is a c program.

My program now works, but I would like to know why I receive so many warnings about an incompatible pointer type. Any ideas? I'm sure it's a simple problem.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
  int x;
  char *y;
 struct CELL *next;
} CELL;

  int list_length(CELL *head){
    int counter;
    CELL *current;
    if(head->next!=NULL){
    current=head->next;
    for(counter=1;current!=NULL;++counter){
      current=current->next;}}
    else
      return 0;
    return counter;}


main(){
  CELL a,b,c,d,e;
  a.next=&b;
  b.next=&c;
  c.next=&d;
  d.next=&e;
  e.next=NULL;
  int l=list_length(&a);
  printf("The list length is %d \n",l);
}
```

Comment: `char y[]` is invalid unless it's the last member of the `struct`.

Comment: Your structure definition is still wrong, you need a structure tag.

Comment: In C `main` has to return an `int` as well. The parameter list to `main` should be `void` or `int argc, char **argv`. The empty parameter list is a C++ declaration, although most compilers don't complain about it.

Comment: Your `list_length` function is still wrong as well. It returns zero for a list of length one and the behavior is undefined for a list of length zero, i.e. a `NULL` pointer. The function I provided below is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to get this program to compile...

1. CELL isn't a type, so you need `struct CELL` in your type declarations
2. A structure requires a semi-colon at the end
3. use `char *` instead of `string` (string isn't a C data type)

As for the algorithm in `list_length()`, you want something more like this:

```
int list_length(struct CELL *head)
{
    int counter = 0;
    while (head) {
        head = head->next;
        ++counter;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

You should also note that your `instantiate()` function returns a pointer to stack-allocated memory resulting in undefined behavior. Move the code from `instantiate()` into the main function.

Here is a complete working program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct CELL {
    struct CELL *next;
};

int list_length(struct CELL *head)
{
    int counter = 0;
    while (head) {
        head = head->next;
        ++counter;
    }
    return counter;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct CELL a, b, c, d, e;
    a.next = &b;
    b.next = &c;
    c.next = &d;
    d.next = &e;
    e.next = NULL;
    printf("The list length is %d \n", list_length(&a));
    return 0;
}
```

To fix the warnings in your latest iteration you need to declare `CELL` something like this:

```
typedef struct CELL_ {
    int x;
    char *y;
    struct CELL_ *next;
} CELL;
```

Comment: Moving the code from `instantiate()` to `main()` is a temporary solution that borders on a hack. Stack-allocated linked list nodes are useful for, say, embedded programming, but general-purpose C programs with an environment should just go ahead and use `malloc`.

Comment: ...and he also needs to `NULL` his last node's `next` member: `e1->next = NULL;`

Comment: Moving the code from `instantiate` to `main` makes it a valid C program. As for the decision not to use `malloc`, that would be a decision specific to the application. The intended application here seems to be an attempt at understanding how linked lists work. I'd say the approach is valid for that case.

Comment: speaking of malloc chris lutz, how exactly do you use it? I am supposed to be familiar with the functions of malloc but I've since forgotten it. can anyone give me a sample of what my program would look like if I used malloc? Aside from this, this post was **extremely** helpful. Thanks very much

Comment: Well, it uses `calloc` which is similar to `malloc`. To understand why you would use `calloc` or `malloc` you need to understand the difference between [stack allocation & heap allocation](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap14/subsection2.1.1.8.html).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included `<string>` and you're missing a semicolon at the end of the structure definition.  Your code has other bugs too, like returning pointers to local variables. It also appears to me that this is a C++ program, but you've tagged it C.

Comment: I'm aware the code originally used `string` instead of `char []` (which is still invalid), but other than that I see no indication that this is supposed to be C++. (I also see no indication that the asker knows either language with any sort of proficiency, but...)

Comment: The original code also used `CELL` by itself (without `struct` or a `typedef`).  I expect the right solution is the opposite of what I saw - ie, an incorrect C program, not an incorrect C++ program.

Answer (score 0):

C has not a `string` data type... Use `char *` instead.